# Why I have to cast this statement in order to get a result?

Tags: java, android, casting

```
private final static int L1_MAX_SCORE = 30;
private final static int L2_MAX_SCORE = 150;

public void UpdateLevel(int score) {
   double progress;

   //returns 0.0
   progress = score / (L2_MAX_SCORE  - L1_MAX_SCORE) * 100;   

   //works correctly.
   progress = (double) score / (L2_MAX_SCORE  - L1_MAX_SCORE) * 100;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic operations in Java whose operands are all `int`s will result in `int`s, so you're actually assigning an integer result to a double variable. Thus you must cast at least one of them to a double so that the calculations are performed based on doubles, because of the higher precision.

Comment: I find it strange that defining the variable (progress) as a double doesn't automatically initiate this behavior.

Comment: Java evaluates the expression on the right hand side first before assigning it to the variable, so I believe by the time the data type is taken into account the result is already an int if you don't cast.

Comment: Why would the type of double affect the computation? Store an int as a double is valid, and dividing ints and expecting an int is valid. So `double progress = 3/4; progress == 0` is a completely legitimate statement. If it automatically set 3/4 to be float division, how would you change the syntax so that you can do what it does now?

Answer (score 2):

Dividing an integer with an integer is defined to do integer division, just like in most (all?) other C-like languages.

By casting `score` to a double, you are dividing a floating-point value with an integer, and you get a floating-point value back.

Answer (score 0):

`L2_MAX_SCORE  - L1_MAX_SCORE` = 150 - 30 = 120

Let's assume score is 30

Using floating point, the answer should be 30/120 = 0.4
With integer division, this will get rounded to 0 hence why it 'doesn't work' - it is actually working, but doing the wrong kind of division for your needs

You can either

- a) Cast either numerator or denominator as double
- b) Rearrange
  the formula to be `(score * 100) / (L2_MAX_SCORE  - L1_MAX_SCORE)`

  - with this, it would become (30 * 100) / 120 = 3000 / 120 = 40
  - it still does integer division, so if the score is 31 your answer (3100
    / 120) is not 25.8333 but 25

Comment: Even if the answer is > 1, the double object still gets populated with 0 without a cast.

Comment: What value are you using for the score? `UpdateLevel(110)` should result in 0.0; while `UpdateLevel(120)` will be 100.0